# Facebook like photo gallery script not working in explorer

Tags: php, css

I found an Ajax `Facebook gallery script` online,It works fine in Firefox,but when i view the same page in Windows internet explorer, its not working.Any ideas how to get it to work.

Am not sure if i should post the script online since its a lot.But this is where i found it,

http://www.script-tutorials.com/facebook-like-photo-gallery-with-comments/

**Result** is @ http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/281/index.php

Comment: Are there any requirements given by the gallery script? Does the script supports Internet Explorer? In which versions of IE does the script not work?

Comment: what is "not working" about it? What version of IE are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look I tested it in IE6 & IE7 to see what was "not working" about it. IE7 seemed to work fine, so I'm guessing you mean IE6.

At a glance I'm guessing it's because

```
position:fixed;
```

is being used in the CSS, and [IE6 doesn't support it](http://caniuse.com/css-fixed)

As to getting it working, you can either do as that site suggests and do a CSS expression for IE6 (although personally I don't like hacks), or you'd have to play around the CSS and get creative. It'll be possible, but could take some time.